# How do I add Microsoft.Graph.Beta to builder.Services.AddAuthentication container?

Tags: c#, blazor

I can add Microsoft.Graph service to a Blazor service app and access v1.0 functions without issue. But when I add the Beta nuget and modify the imports I get an "Reference to type IAuthenticationProvider claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.Graph.Core', but it could not be found" error

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzHd8.png)